# Get notification using file observer

Tags: java, android

I am using File Observer to get notification.But I get notification after the file has deleted . Is it possible to notify before file deletion ?

Comment: Are you using Java to delete the file or the deletion is handled by OS process ?

Comment: By OS only. Like "file.delete()"

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not. The observer will simply tell you what's already happened. The only way to intercept the deletion before it happens is to write either a device driver to be loaded on the system or a C library that's started with the program that's deleting the file.